# txt.snippets-file not loaded

Tags: vim, code-snippets, ultisnips

As a windows user my `.snippets`-files are located at `$HOME\vimfiles\Ultisnips`.
I created some snippets to use in `.txt`-files and stored them in a file named `txt.snippets`. 
When i created a new .txt-file they weren't available. So for testing if they worked at all I renamed the file to `all.snippets`, as this file didn't exist before, and they suddenly worked as intended.


 Is there another way to make `.txt`-snippets work besides adding them to `all.snippets`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `foo` in `foo.snippets` doesn't refer to the `.foo` extension, but to the `foo` filetype, that Vim may or may not derive from the `.foo` extension.

In this case, Vim assigns the `text` filetype to files with the `.txt` extension so your snippets, which depend on the `txt` filetype, are not active.

Renaming your snippet file to `text.snippets` should solve your problem.

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot. Seems like i should read some more about filetypes.